# Load environment properties before running an application jar file

Tags: java, linux

I usually ran my application simply by using `java -jar path/to/app.jar` command on the Terminal on my MacOS. However, one dependency is forcing me to read some properties from the System properties so those need to be present in the runtime as env variables.

I'm able to run the application in IntelliJ by adding all those properties in a file in my project resource directory and use [EnvFile](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7861-envfile) plugin. This didn't require any modifications to the way I used to run the application on IntelliJ.

However, when it comes to running the application on console, I can't find a better way to run it using the above `java -jar path/to/app.jar` file.

Please note, I can't pass those properties as `-DpropertyName=value` to the above command as those will be accessed by `System.getProperty()` in the application. I'm referring to feeding the properties into the environment because the dependency will access those by `System.getenv().get()` command.

One way I can think of to use a shell script to load these properties into the environment followed by the `java -jar path/to/app.jar` command. Please let me know if there's a better way to achieve this.

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: @cyberbrain I'm using MacOS. I'll update that in my description.

Answer (score 0):

On most OSes, environment properties aren't global; instead, each process has their own table, but whenever a new process is spawned, some other process is its spawner (for example, if you run stuff on the terminal, the shell spawns these processes; if you use `ProcessBuilder` in java, the JVM process spawns it, and so on. Only the system init launcher has no spawner, and all system services are spawned by the init process) - and any newly spawned process gets a clone of the environment table as it was in the spawning process as it is launched.

In addition, when launching, you *can* make a change to that if you want. In java, `ProcessBuilder` has method calls if you want to do that.

A shell application (that big black box thing is nothing magical, it's just an app) has tools for this too. For example, on most shells, you can do this:

```
MYPROPERTY=foo java -jar whatever.jar
```

At which point `System.getenv("MYPROPERTY")` inside that java process would return `FOO`. (bash knows that `MYPROPERTY=foo` is not itself an executable file to run, because of the `=` sign.

You can put multiple strings in there if you like:

```
PROP1=foo PROP2=bar java -jar ....
```

works fine. The other option is to first set these things, then spawn. But on most shells, you have to use `export`:

```
export PROP1=foo
export PROP2=bar
java -jar ...
```

Because without `export` those things aren't provided to the newly spawned process.